# jquery on search filter - wrap <optgroup> if no <option> matches [ Safari Browser ]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

this code is working fine but the problem is with `optgroup` as if no result found `option` gets `$.wrap()` but i am unable to wrap `optgroup` if no result found.

```js
$('.search').on('keyup keydown', function(){
  searchFilter($(this).val());
});

function searchFilter(value){
  $('option').each(function(){
    if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) >= 0){
      $(this).removeClass('hidden');
      $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
      
      if($(this).parent().is('span')){
        $(this).unwrap('<span>');
      }
    }else{
      $(this).addClass('hidden');
      $(this).prop('disabled', true);
      
      if(!$(this).parent().is('span')){
        $(this).wrap('<span>');
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.hidden{
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="search" />

<div class="row">
  <select multiple style="width: 150px;height:200px" id="search">
    <optgroup label="test01">
      <option>car</option>
      <option>bike</option>
      <option>cycle</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="test02">
      <option>orange</option>
      <option>apple</option>
      <option>pineapple</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: why are you wrapping with `span`?

Comment: @AswinKumar i mention Safari browser in question, in safari we can't **hide** `option` or `optgroup` just by applying `display:none`, this need to `$.wrap()` a html tag to hide it.

Comment: Note that `span` is not a vaild child of `select` so you're not guaranteed to get consistent results by wrapping `optgroup` with a `span` anyway. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Comment: @JonP i know but i found no option to hide it for safari browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i Search for too long, and got solved from my senior. ended up with this solution.
thanks for all your help

```js
$('.search').on('keyup keydown', function(){
  searchFilter($(this).val());
});

function searchFilter(value){
  $('option').each(function(){
    if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) >= 0){
      $(this).removeClass('hidden');
      $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
      
      if($(this).parent().is('span')){
        $(this).unwrap('<span>');
      }
    }else{
      $(this).addClass('hidden');
      $(this).prop('disabled', true);
      
      if(!$(this).parent().is('span')){
        $(this).wrap('<span>');
      }
    }
  });
  $('optgroup').each(function () {
    var qq = $(this).find('span option').length;
    var len = $(this).find('option').length;
    if ($(this).parent().is('span')) {
        $(this).unwrap('<span>');
    }
    if (qq == len) {
        $(this).wrap('<span>');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.hidden{
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="search" />

<div class="row">
  <select multiple style="width: 150px;height:200px" id="search">
    <optgroup label="test01">
      <option>car</option>
      <option>bike</option>
      <option>cycle</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="test02">
      <option>orange</option>
      <option>apple</option>
      <option>pineapple</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hiding `optgroups` and `options` are probably not the way to go, even by wrapping in a `span`. Wrapping in `<span style="disaply:none">` doesn't work when I tested it in Safari mobile.

Your better option is to remove the items you don't want from the dropdown. In doing this you'll want to create a clone of the original dropdown so there is a record of the initial state.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Add a hidden clone
  var clone = $("#fancy").clone(true);
  clone.attr("id", "fancy_clone");
  clone.css("display", "none");
  $("body").append(clone);

  $('.search').on('keyup', function() {
    searchFilter($(this).val());
  });

  function searchFilter(value) {
    //Need a working clone - keep our clone as the original record
    var workingClone = $("#fancy_clone").clone(true);
    $("#fancy").empty();

    //Remove unwanted options
    $(workingClone).find("option").each(function() {
      if ($(this).val().toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) === -1) {
        var thisParent = $(this).parents("optgroup");
        $(this).remove();

        //remove optgroup if it is empty
        if ($(thisParent).children("option").length === 0) {
          $(thisParent).remove();
        }
      }
    });

    //UPdate the actual select
    $("#fancy").append($(workingClone).html());
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="search" />
<select id="fancy">
  <optgroup label="test01">
    <option value="car">car</option>
    <option value="bike">bike</option>
    <option value="cycle">cycle</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="test02">
    <option value="orange">orange</option>
    <option value="apple">apple</option>
    <option value="pinapple">pineapple</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `!` your `searchFilter` function
line 13

So result

```js
$('.search').on('keyup keydown', function(){
  searchFilter($(this).val());
});

function searchFilter(value){
  $('option').each(function(){
    if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) >= 0){
      $(this).removeClass('hidden');
      $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
      
      if($(this).parent().is('span')){
        $(this).unwrap('<span>');
      }
    }else{
      $(this).addClass('hidden');
      $(this).prop('disabled', true);
      
      if($(this).parent().is('span')){
        $(this).wrap('<span>');
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.hidden{
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="search" />

<div class="row">
  <select multiple style="width: 150px;height:200px" id="search">
    <optgroup label="test01">
      <option>car</option>
      <option>bike</option>
      <option>cycle</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="test02">
      <option>orange</option>
      <option>apple</option>
      <option>pineapple</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: friend it's not even working in snippet, please read my question carefully.